# Running two Gradle application tasks concurrently in same project

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

It looks like when I try to run a second Gradle task for the same project in a different window, the second one blocks on a lock. Is there a straightforward way around this?

What I'm trying to do: My project has a couple server subprojects that both use the application plugin. I'd like to start both (e.g., `$ gradle :server1:run`) so I could connect and try them out.

I know I can write a task to deploy the two servers to a test area and start them there, but the application:run task is convenient during development for one application, so I'd like to use it for two if possible.

I'm using Gradle 2.7.

Comment: It seems that this is possible however you write a custom task that starts both servers in background.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing. Rather than using the application plugin's `run` task, I used `installDist`, and wrote a simple task to run the generated start script. Then I extended it by creating a simple service script that I stored under `src/dist/bin`. The script handles start, stop, and status operations. The final result:

```
ext.installDir = "$buildDir/install/" + project.name
ext.command = "$installDir/bin/" + project.name

task start(type:Exec, dependsOn:'installDist') {
  description "Starts the " + applicationName + " application"
  workingDir "$installDir"
  commandLine "$command", "start"
}

task stop(type:Exec, dependsOn:'installDist') {
  description "Stops the " + applicationName + " application"
  workingDir "$installDir"
  commandLine "$command", "stop"
}

task status(type:Exec, dependsOn:'installDist') {
  description "Displays the " + applicationName + " application status"
  workingDir "$installDir"
  commandLine "$command", "status"
}
```

Now from the parent project I can just type:

```
$ gradlew start
```

to start both servers and

```
$ gradlew stop
```

to shut them both down.